# Google charts API Y is axis scaling data

Tags: graph, google-visualization, linegraph

I am using the following data default data:
37.705 54.098 55.738 75.41 52.459 73.77 68.852 55.738

```
//chart.googleapis.com/chart
   ?chxs=0,676767,11.5,0,l,676767
   &chxt=y
   &chs=300x225
   &cht=lc
   &chco=3D7930
   &chd=s:Xhiugtqi
   &chg=14.3,-1,1,1
   &chls=2,4,0
   &chm=B,C5D4B5BB,0,0,0
```

[image: Normal plot]

My question is, why (and how do you stop) google charts from rescaling your data when you change the range of the y-axis?

For instance here I cap the y-axis range to 40 but it scales all data down... this is bad for me. I need it to show the actual data values no matter what the y-axis cap is.

```
//chart.googleapis.com/chart
   ?chxr=0,0,40
   &chxs=0,676767,11.5,0,l,676767
   &chxt=y
   &chs=300x225
   &cht=lc
   &chco=3D7930
   &chd=s:Xhiugtqi
   &chg=14.3,-1,1,1
   &chls=2,4,0
   &chm=B,C5D4B5BB,0,0,0
```

[image: see it scaled all the data values! What a crappy thing to do]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just figured it out.  If you set your own max and min values for the range, it will scale the data.

So this can be resolved by setting the axis range to 'actual' values:

```
//chart.googleapis.com/chart
   ?chxr=0,0,40
   &chxs=0,676767,11.5,0,l,676767
   &chxt=y
   &chs=300x225
   &cht=lc
   &chco=3D7930
   &chd=s:Xhiugtqi
   &chg=14.3,-1,1,1
   &chls=2,4,0
   &chm=B,C5D4B5BB,0,0,0
   &chds=a
```